# Performance tuning in iterating through FileSystemObject Collections

Tags: performance, filesystemobject, fso

I don't know how much the system stores in memory at this line `For Each objFile in objFolder.Files` and whether iterating using something like `objFile.Files.Count` would be more beneficial. Does anyone knows if using the following code would create any significant performance issues?

```
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Get the folder object associated with the directory
Dim objFolder
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\InetPub\wwwroot")

Response.Write "The files found in " & objFolder.Name & ":<br>"

'Loop through the Files collection
Dim objFile
For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
  Response.Write objFile.Name & "<br>"
Next

'Clean up!
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how much the system stores in memory at this line For Each objFile in objFolder.Files

Not sure what you mean but this will just loop over a collection of File **objects** which will not use a lot of memory. This call will clearly not load the content of the files in memory if that is your question.